# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String in flutter i am using ImagePicker

Tags: json, flutter, list, http, flutter-dependencies

I just want to say that I am using an Image_picker to take Images from the camera but the problem is Error is not showing in the emulator but Real Mobile device.

After clicking on Submit  button I got the error -> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String

} catch (e) { throw e; // here } please help me i dont understand how solve

Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String` final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var logID = sharedPreferences.getInt('logID');

```
  String clientNo1 = sharedPreferences.getString('ClientNo');
  var uID1 = sharedPreferences.getInt('uID');
 
  const String baseurl ="url for Post method";
  var json = {
    "AccessToken": "2A9LOSJJMSJDUUDND907782",
    "ClientNo": clientNo1,
    "uID": uID1,
    "logID": logID,
    "vID": vIDpss,
    "PTID": pIDpass,
    "Name": propertyNameController.text,
    "Size": sourceOfSizes,
    "PlotStatus": 'Available',
    "UseFor": 'Sales',
    "GrossSize": grossSizeController.text.isNotEmpty
        ? grossSizeController.text
        : null,
    "Description": descriptionController.text.isNotEmpty
        ? descriptionController.text
        : null,
    "Amount": rentAmountController.text,
    "Lat": latitude,
    "Log": longitude,
    "Address":
        addressController.text.isNotEmpty ? addressController.text : null,
    "Images": [{
             "Name":AYHS78.jpg,
              "Size":130.9,
              "Value":Base64Image,
              },
              {
             "Name": AYMJ78.jpg,
              "Size":100.9,
              "Value":Base64Image,
              },{
             "Name": AOLIS78.jpg,
              "Size":123.9,
              "Value":Base64Image,
              },{
             "Name": AIKUU78.jpg,
              "Size":109.9,
              "Value":Base64Image,
              },
             ]};
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("jason data form add property");
    print(json);
  }
  var body = jsonEncode(json);
  print(body);
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(baseurl),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: body,
  );
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("response.StatusCode:${response.statusCode}");
  }

  Map res = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print(res);
  }
  if (res['Code'] == 200) {
    showStatus(res['Message'], Colors.green);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(" ${res['Message']}");
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => const ActivePage()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  } else if (res['Code'] == 202) {
    showStatus(" ${res['Message']}", Colors.red);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  } else if (res['Code'] == 203) {
    showStatus(res['Message'], Colors.black);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  } else if (res['Code'] == 204) {
    showStatus('Exception', Colors.blueGrey);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  } else {
    showStatus(res.toString(), Colors.purple);
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
} on Exception catch (exception) {
  print('Exception');
  print(exception);
  showStatus(exception.toString(), Colors.purple);
  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });
} catch (error) {
  print('Error');
  print(error);
  showStatus(error.toString(), Colors.pinkAccent);
  setState(() {
    isLoading = false;
  });
}`
```

Actually, I want to highlight when Images have a single value `" Images": [{"Name": AYHS78.jpg, "Size":130.9, "Value": Base64Image}],` HTTP Post method is successfully but when it has more than two data value is shown error. and also makeimage Class this method

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
jsonDecode(response.body);
```

to

```
response.body;
```